# Can't upload photo. Says "The upload path does not appear to be valid."

Tags: categories

I am trying to upload photos to one of my categories on my site which I have done several times before but it is now telling me that "The upload path does not appear to be valid."  How can I fix this so I can upload my pictures to my site?  I can go to another category and it will allow but not under the one I need.

Comment: We gonna need more info, Kathy. Are you trying to set one category image? Or to upload a image to a custom channel field? Is this field on a different channel from the other ones you say the upload works?

Comment: Yes Kathy, could you be more thorough in explaining exactly what is going on? Can you still view other images that you've previously uploaded to that category and channel? What steps have you tried besides just asking this stackexchange forum?